# How to make higher-order component generic?

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out the syntax to make this component generic. The signature is:

```
const Select = forwardRef<HTMLSelectElement, SelectProps>(function Select({onChange,options: _options,value,...props}, forwardedRef) {
   ...
}
```

But `SelectProps` is actually generic:

```
type SelectProps<T> = { ... }
```

So the type of `Select` should be:

```
type SelectComponent<T> = ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<SelectProps<T>> & RefAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>>
```

(That's from the return value of `forwardRef`)

But I can't figure out how to add the `<T>` to `const Select = ...`

This doesn't work:

```
const Select: SelectComponent = forwardRef...
```

Because "TS2314: Generic type 'SelectComponent' requires 1 type argument(s)." but I don't want to specify the type argument, I want the caller to specify it.

How do I type this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is to cast the result of `forwardRef()` back into its original form before being wrapped. This requires you to refactor a bit to pull out the inner component and make it fully generic:

```js
type SelectProps<T> = {
  onChange: (newValue: T) => null;
  options: any;
  value: T;
};

function SelectInner<T>(
  { onChange, options: _options, value, ...props }: SelectProps<T>,
  forwardedRef: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLSelectElement>
) {
  return null;
}

const Select = forwardRef(SelectInner) as typeof SelectInner;
```

Another option is to [augment the `forwardRef` type definition](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-generic-forward-refs/#option-3%3A-augment-forwardref) to be more what you want, which is perhaps more useful if you intend to be doing this *a lot*. If you look closely, this is essentially the same thing as the option above, just defined in a way such that it applies to all `forwardRef()` instances.

```js
declare module 'react' {
  function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(
    render: (props: P, ref: React.Ref<T>) => React.ReactElement | null
  ): (props: P & React.RefAttributes<T>) => React.ReactElement | null;
}

type SelectProps<T> = {
  onChange: (newValue: T) => null;
  options: any;
  value: T;
};

const Select = forwardRef(
  (
    { onChange, options: _options, value, ...props }: SelectProps<T>,
    forwardedRef: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    return null;
  }
);
```

Note: in either case using `React.ForwardedRef` requires the latest `@types/react` to be installed. [Source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L560)